# How to prevent Asynchronous execution in odoo 10?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-10

I am trying to call a controller function from js and use the result for validation purpose.
Unfortunately, the result getting as `undefined` because of the result line is printing before the completion of the ajax call.

here is my code:

***.js**

```
send: function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var self = this;
var is_submit = self.$target.find('#is_submit').val();
var mobile = self.$target.find('#mobile').val();
var phone = self.$target.find('#phone').val();
var data = self.ajaxcall(mobile,e);
console.log('dddddddd',data);// here it prints undefined.
if (data == false){
  return false;
}
this._super(e);

},
})


ajaxcall:function(mobile,e){
var value = {
  'flag':'mobile',
  'number':mobile
}
ajax.jsonRpc('/checkexisting/','call',value).then(function(data){
  console.log('isnide ajax call',data);
  return data;
});
```

},

Here is th console output:

[image]

How can i make it as a synchronous mode?

Comment: For this, easiest solution is add a callback function also You can try with Async.js or Syncify.js library

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to to make all code synchronous, you can use `callbacks` or `promises/await` to wait for the response.

Example with callback:

```
{
            send: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var self = this;
                var is_submit = self.$target.find('#is_submit').val();
                var mobile = self.$target.find('#mobile').val();
                var phone = self.$target.find('#phone').val();
                var data = self.ajaxcall(mobile, function(result){
                    console.log('the result is: ', result)
                    self._super(e);
                });

            },
            ajaxcall: function (mobile, callback) {
                var value = {
                    'flag': 'mobile',
                    'number': mobile
                }
                ajax.jsonRpc('/checkexisting/', 'call', value).then(function (data) {
                    console.log('isnide ajax call', data);
                    callback(data);
                });
            }
```

Example with promises:

```
{
            send: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var self = this;
                var is_submit = self.$target.find('#is_submit').val();
                var mobile = self.$target.find('#mobile').val();
                var phone = self.$target.find('#phone').val();
                var data = self.ajaxcall(mobile).then(function(result){
                    console.log('the result is: ', result)
                    self._super(e);
                });

            },
            ajaxcall: function (mobile) {
                var value = {
                    'flag': 'mobile',
                    'number': mobile
                }

                return new Promise(function(res, rej){
                    ajax.jsonRpc('/checkexisting/', 'call', value).then(function (data) {
                        console.log('isnide ajax call', data);
                        res(data);
                    })
                });
            }
```

Or with await(note the `async` and `await` keywords):

```
{
            send: async function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var self = this;
                var is_submit = self.$target.find('#is_submit').val();
                var mobile = self.$target.find('#mobile').val();
                var phone = self.$target.find('#phone').val();
                var data = await self.ajaxcall(mobile);

                console.log(data)

                self._super(e);

            },
            ajaxcall: function (mobile) {
                var value = {
                    'flag': 'mobile',
                    'number': mobile
                }

                return new Promise(function(res, rej){
                    ajax.jsonRpc('/checkexisting/', 'call', value).then(function (data) {
                        console.log('isnide ajax call', data);
                        res(data);
                    })
                });
            }
```

Comment: @MaatenDev, I tried with callback, but the control didn't go to ajaxcall function. it skipped directly to  this._super();

Comment: @MaatenDev, in othr two options i am getting this error:

`TypeError: ajax.jsonRpc(...).then(...).catch is not a function`

Comment: I updated the callback and promise examples @KbiR

Comment: @MaatenDev, Now i am getting below error:
`TypeError: this is undefined`

Comment: Fixed the error, please check again @KbiR

Comment: @MaatenDev, now getting this error: TypeError: self._super is not a function

Comment: Could you add the _super method to your question? I don't see it anywhere @KbiR?

Comment: Actually, i am inheriting send funciton, so after execution of my custom code i need to execute the parent function. For this purpose we use this._super();

Comment: Super only works for constructors, so _super seems like a custom method? How are you  inheriting the methods. Could you show the parent class/object? @KbiR